# MySql: Restrict update permission on one column in one table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table, lets call it student, in a schema called enrollment. Table student has a column called address that I don't want a certain user to update (other permissions are fine such as select, insert). All other columns in that table AND in that schema should have the update privilege.

Is this doable?

Comment: one way is building a hierarchy of rights via a table or two (roughly) and enforce it in a trigger

Answer (score 3):

You can set privileges on database / table / column.  But I really would not try to use MySQL's privilege mechanism at that level.  I would instead write application code to decide who can see/change what.  This is more flexible in the long run.  And more graceful to the user -- instead of getting a cryptic MySQL error message about permissions, the UI would simply not show what should not be shown.  For updating, the UI would not even give the user the option.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted a specific application to be able to update only 1 field (my_field) in only 1 table (table_name) while being able to read the entire database.

I created a special user for that purpose:

```sql
CREATE USER 'restrictedUser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD_HERE';
SET PASSWORD FOR 'restrictedUser'@'%' = PASSWORD('PASSWORD_HERE');
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'restrictedUser'@'%';
GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE_NAME.* TO 'restrictedUser'@'%';
GRANT UPDATE (my_field) ON DATABASE_NAME.table_name TO 'restrictedUser'@'%';
```

Documentation for Column privilege can be found here for [mariaDb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/#column-privileges) and here for [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-column-privileges)