# Is there a way to make a specific column in MySQL only allow INSERT, but not UPDATE or DELETE?

Tags: mysql

For example, I have a table called `stuff` and it has a column called `name`.

I want my users to be able to `INSERT` into the `name` column, but not `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.

I know I can control this from the middle-tier business logic code, but is there some way to also prevent this at the MySQL database level for extra security?

I did see an old answer on SO about triggers but it's from 2013 and is probably out of date. I'm looking for a MySQL 8 answer.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to get granular with columns, trigger no longer necessary. However, [see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40226673/7644018) about avoiding the need at the MySQL level. (it can get tricky and involved rather quickly)

Comment: I understand that. But I'd still like to know how to do it.

Comment: Ok, then [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46721984/7644018)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution is to implement permissions on users or groups:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-column-privileges

```
GRANT SELECT (col1), INSERT (col1, col2) ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

So you your case it would be something like:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES on mydb.stuff to 'userorgroup'@'somehost'

GRANT INSERT(name) ON mydb.stuff TO 'userorgroup'@'somehost'
```